# No dependencies were set for resolution

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I run tests using Arquillian integration testing framework.
"Arquillian does not use the entire classpath to isolate the test archive. Instead, it uses the ShrinkWrap class, that is a Java API for creating archives. When we create the archive to test, we specify what files to include in the classpath to use the test. During the deployment, ShrinkWrap isolates only the classes needed for the test" ([Introduction to Testing with Arquillian](http://www.baeldung.com/arquillian)).

There is my configurations:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    MavenResolverSystem resolver = Maven.resolver();
    File[] files = resolver.loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();

    WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war");
    webArchive.addAsLibraries(files)
            .addClasses("There I add my classess")
    .addAsManifestResource("arquillian/arquillian.xml");

    System.out.println(webArchive.toString(true));
    return webArchive;
}
```

And pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-embedded-8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-spi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But I am getting errors with stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive com.project.MyControllerTest.createDeployment()
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No dependencies were set for resolution
INFO: Stopping service [arquillian-tomcat-embedded]
```

What I've missed?

Comment: I just solved this problem using shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain. I'm using 3.1.3 version and it worked out.